# flutter_inappwebview 5.3.2 package crashes the app when choosing a file or an image

Tags: flutter, dart, android-webview

I'm using [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) package because after some research I found that it's the only webview package that supports the features the I need, one of them is uploading a file to a certain website, I tried the example app [flutter_inappwebview example](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview) and everything worked perfectly except when I try to select an image or a file from a website, it suddenly crashes and closes the app, so how can I fix this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved by using [this](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/5.x.x/intro#enable-camera-for-html-inputs) configuration

Comment: Hey Ahmad, the link you have provided is no longer available. Please make sure to provide a permanent explanation when providing answers and avoid urls as they may stop working after some time.

Comment: probably ment this official link :) https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview/versions/5.0.5

Answer (score 3):

**STEP 1**
Configure Android
On Android, you need to add these permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml file to be able to use camera for taking images and videos:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIDEO_CAPTURE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUDIO_CAPTURE" />
```

**STEP 2**

Also, you need to add the following code inside the  tag of your **AndroidManifest** file:

```
<provider
android:name="com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.InAppWebViewFileProvider"
android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_inappwebview.fileprovider"
android:exported="false"
android:grantUriPermissions="true">
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
```